# Number keypad jumping after UIAlertview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertview

I have a login screen that shows an alert when the user gets the password wrong on a number of occasions.  On clicking one of the buttons, another alert view is presented to confirm, if I press the cancel button on this second alert view, the number keypad bounces from the bottom of the screen back up to its original position.  No code is being executed during this second alert response.  Can someone help?

```
if (loginCount < 5) {
  // Display alert to user
  UIAlertView *loginError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failure" message:@"You have entered an incorrect passcode.  Please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [loginError show];

  } else {
    // Display alert to user, including option to reset the app as they have 5 or more login failures
    UIAlertView *loginError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Login Failure" message: @"You have entered an incorrect passcode on 5 or more occasions.  Please try again or reset the app." delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Try Again" otherButtonTitles: @"Reset App", nil]
    [loginError show];
}
// Clear password fields
[self clearPasswordFields];
[passcode1 becomeFirstResponder];
// Increment the login count
loginCount++;

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    // If the user has chosen to reset the app, alert with a confirmation first before resetting
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([title isEqualToString:@"Reset App"]) {
        // Create alert to give the user the choice to confirm reset
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm Reset" message:@"Are you sure you wish to Reset?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [alert show];
    } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Yes"] && buttonIndex == 1) {
        [Utilities resetApp];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i will do it.

in the header file:

```
UIAlertView *loginError;
```

in the implementation file:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  if (loginCount < 5) {
  // Display alert to user
  loginError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failure" message:@"You have entered an incorrect passcode.  Please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [loginError show];

  } else {
    // Display alert to user, including option to reset the app as they have 5 or more login failures
    loginError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Login Failure" message: @"You have entered an incorrect passcode on 5 or more occasions.  Please try again or reset the app." delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Try Again" otherButtonTitles: @"Reset App", nil]
    [loginError show];
}
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    // If the user has chosen to reset the app, alert with a confirmation first before resetting
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([title isEqualToString:@"Reset App"]) {
        [self showSecondAlert];
    } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Yes"] && buttonIndex == 1) {
        [Utilities resetApp];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }else{
      [self clearPasswordFields];
      [passcode1 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}

-(void)showSecondAlert
{
        //make sure you dismiss the old alertview first
         [loginError dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0  animated:NO];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm Reset" message:@"Are you sure you wish to Reset?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [alert show];
}
```

Hope this helps...